# Match hyphen-split IP ranges when the first digits in the third section differ (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

All IP ranges are written the way they are shown in examples, i.e. split with a hyphen.

Match:

```
109.240.40.0-109.240.84.255
84.250.86.0-84.250.90.125
75.123.49.0-75.123.50.243
109.240.125.0-109.240.137.255
84.250.155.0-84.250.255.125
75.123.215.0-75.123.240.243
```

Don't Match:

```
109.240.40.0-109.240.45.255
84.250.86.0-84.250.88.125
75.123.45.0-75.123.46.243
109.240.125.0-109.240.129.255
84.250.155.0-84.250.158.125
75.123.215.0-75.123.216.243
```

So, in the third section of the IP address range, the FIRST digit of 2-digit sections must NOT match, as well as the FIRST ONE OR TWO digits of 3-digit sections.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?...

Comment: Also which language / regex dialect are you targeting?

Comment: I'm targeting Notepad++. I suck at regex, so I don't think there's a need to post my mere attempts, which were all marked as invalid expressions.
But ok, here's one of the attempts:

\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1}\d{1}\.\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.(?!\3)\d{1}\.\d{1,3}\r\n

Comment: Tried this:

^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1}\d{1}\.)\d{1,3}-(?!\1)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1}\d{1}\.\d{1,3}\r\n



It matches all ranges where the third section consisting of 2 digits is different, even if only the second digit is different.

Comment: Does this match?: `1.2.34.56-1.2.44.56`

Comment: Yes, it should match, because the first digit of the third section is different (3 and 4, respectively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made it myself:

```
^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1})\d{1}\.\d{1,3}-(?!\1)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1}\d{1}\.\d{1,3}\r\n|^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{2})\d{1}\.\d{1,3}-(?!\2)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{2}\d{1}\.\d{1,3}\r\n
```